# Permission.storage.request() showing permanentDenied in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am creating an app with backup facility...

I want to create a backup file and want to store on download folder,

but before i coode for it, its not showing permission window to allow creating a folder or file....

here is code

```
  void onBackup() async{
  var status=await Permission.storage.status;

  if(!status.isGranted)
   {
    final answer= await Permission.storage.request();
    print("Answer ="+answer.toString());
    //printing Answer =PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied
   }
  else
    {
      print('Granted');
    }
  }
```